# Python - Tasks returns a newly initialized task

Tags: python, queue, task

I am having trouble with the wording, and what it is asking me to do? Any clear on this or tips? Thank you

```
class Task():
    __slots__ = ( 'task', 'priority' )

def mkTask(myName, myPriority):
```

I have to modified mkTask(myName, myPriority) that takes a task name (a string) and a priority (an integer), creates and returns a newly initialized Task object with them.

Still don't quite understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being asked to instanciate a `Task` object (which means, create a new object from the class), then set its attributes to the function arguments you get passed in, and return that object.

Something like this:

```
def mkTask(myName, myPriority):
    task = Task()
    task.task = myName
    task.priority = myPriority
    return task
```

To test the `mkTask` function, you could do

```
mkTask('foobar', 5)
```

Think of the class as a template for objects. You can create as many objects from one class as you want, and set their attributes to different values.

Comment: Oh okay, gottca. I was confusing about the wording, the examples you gave me, it makes sense now. I was confused. Thanks!

Comment: I had to wait 8 minutes before I can accept the answer. I did now!